# Why @SkipSelf decorator doesn't work like injectort.get(Foo, ..., InjectFlags.SkipSelf)?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm stuck on something I didn't expect.

I'm in a situation where my childComponent needs to inject `SomeService` and provide its own `SomeService`.
All works fine if I use the `@SkipSelf()` decorator on the parent `SomeService`.

But I'd like to keep the constructor signature as simple as possible (cause ChildComponent will be a base class in the real implementation);
So I tried to use the Injector instead, like this:

`this.parentService = injector.get(SomeService, undefined, InjectFlags.SkipSelf);`

By using the injector I get the same service provided by the ChildComponent, any clue? Am I expecting the flags to work in a wrong way?

This is a very simple example of what I'm trying to do
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhfbel

Injector docs
https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get

Thank you all in advance

Comment: AFAIK there is no such signature for `Injector` which supports flags

Comment: try using `constructor(@SkipSelf() injector: Injector)` instead.

Comment: @yurzui actually there is [Injector.get](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get), I should have added it to the post, sorry.   
  
@Reactgular that solution works, but it doesn't really give me an advantage. I'd like to have just `constructor(private inj: Injector)`

Comment: Actually you're getting Element Injector in your component and it doesn't support taking flags as a parameter. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/da2880d7c495022405102f89b8c641b23516388d/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L337

Comment: @yurzui you're right.  The funny thing is that they actually handle the "flag" feature [at line 342](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/da2880d7c495022405102f89b8c641b23516388d/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L342)